# Ansible reports "permission denied" when issuing command on remote host

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.1
Ansible host: Ubuntu 16.04
Remote host: CentOS 6.5

I'm quite new to Ansible. I have a simple ansible project:

```
├── hosts
├── roles
│   └── setup
│       ├── defaults
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── tasks
│       │   └── main.yml
│       └── templates
│           └── automation-agent.config.j2
└── site.yml
```

Command I used to run playbook:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml --user admin --ask-pass`

On the remote host, I have set up user `admin` with root priviledge:

```
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
admin   ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

However, one of the playbook tasks ran into issue:

```
- name: Back up Automation Agent config file if exists
  command: mv /etc/mongodb-mms/automation-agent.config /etc/mongodb-mms/automation-agent.config.bak
```

Ansible reports:

```
TASK [setup : Back up Automation Agent config file if exists] ******************
fatal: [192.168.241.135]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["mv", "/etc/mongodb-mms/automation-agent.config", "/etc/mongodb-mms/automation-agent.config.bak"], "delta": "0:00:00.002588", "end": "2016-06-01 22:57:55.577158", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2016-06-01 22:57:55.574570", "stderr": "mv: cannot move `/etc/mongodb-mms/automation-agent.config' to `/etc/mongodb-mms/automation-agent.config.bak': Permission denied", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Noted that permission setting on `/etc/mongodb-mms/automation-agent.config` is `0600`

`-rw-------. 1 mongod mongod 313 Jun  1 04:48 automation-agent.config`

Apparently one would need `sudo` priviledge to make changes to this file. I have tried Ansible's `--become` and `--become-user`, but not having success.

`ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml --user admin --ask-pass --become --become-user admin`

What should I do in Ansible to gain `sudo` and make changes to that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `--become-user admin`, so you're essentially doing `sudo -u admin`, but you intend to become `root` (`sudo -u root`).

Don't specify `--become-user admin` *or* use `--become-user root`, and Ansible by default will try to become `root`.

If you need to specify a password for becoming `root`, use the `--ask-become-pass` flag.

If you don't want to be prompted for a `sudo` password when using `sudo`, your `sudoers` entry for the `admin` user should read as follows instead:

```
admin   ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: `ask-become-pass` works. The whole command I use now is `ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml --user admin --ask-pass --become --ask-become-pass`

Comment: `ansible -i 10.0.250.74, --user admin --ask-pass --become --ask-become-pass all -m ansible.builtin.user -a "append=yes groups=wheel name=ansible"` **worked** for me too. Managed node CentOS release 6.10 (Final) 2.6.32-754.27.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Jan 28 14:40:29 UTC 2020 i686 with Python 2.6.6, control node macOS Catalina 10.15.7 BuildVersion: 19H2 ansible 2.10.2 python version = 3.8.6 (default, Oct  8 2020, 14:06:32) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)]